# Discrete Math - Hasse Diagrams

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

This is one of many questions of similar type I have to do for an assignment and im troubled with what to do. The question is as follows:

> Consider a relation R defined on the set A = {−7, −6, −5, −4, −3, −2,
>   −1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}. Determine for the following if the
>   relations are reflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric, transitive,
>   partial orders, equivalence relations. (a) R = {(a, b)|a ≤ b}, if this
>   is a partial order, draw the Hasse diagram.

I understand the definitions of what symmetric, anti-symmetric, reflexive and transitive are but im troubled with understanding a partial order. Also how can one draw a hasse diagram? Is there any logic/rules to apply?

thanks!

Comment: The "im troubled with understanding a partial order" is a little vague. Can you be more clear?

Comment: @GitGud amWhy just answered the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw a Hasse diagram of a **finite** poset follow the algorithm below, but first notice that on any finite poset $P$, given $x,y\in P$ such that $x\neq y$, then $x$ and $y$ aren't comparable or there is a chain of [covers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_relation) from one to the other.

Now for the algorithm: Let $x,y,z\in P$

1. To each $p\in P$ associate a point $(a_p,b_p)$ on the euclidean plane in such a way that $x<y$, then $b_x<b_y$, if $x\neq y$.
2. If $x$ is covered by $y$, then draw a line from $(a_x,b_x)$ to $(a_y,b_y)$.
3. Ensure that, if $x\neq z\neq y$, $(a_z, b_z)$ is not in the line that goes from $(a_x,b_x)$ to $(a_y,b_y)$.

Answer (score 1):

A ***partial order*** is any relation that is reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive.

An ***equivalence relation*** is any relation that is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

See if you can show that your relation $R$ is a partial order on set $A$ and why it is, but it is not an equivalence relation and why it is not.

A **[Hasse diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram)** shows visually, for a [partially ordered set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set), how elements "compare": in this case, you have a partially ordered set, with a total order, and can be thought of as a *chain*.

Comment: Were you able to draw a Hasse diagram, choloboy7? Did you get a *chain*? Let me know your progress...;-)