# Hasse Diagram for cube functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do you draw a hasse Diagram for the following example

Consider a relation $R$ deﬁned on the set $A = \{-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$. Determine for the $R = \{(a, b) : a^3 = b^3\}$ if the relation is reﬂexive, symmetric, anti -symmetric, transitive, partial orders or an equivalence relation.

I have figured out whether it is reﬂexive, symmetric, anti -symmetric, transitive, partial orders or equivalence relations. But cant draw the hasse diagram.

Comment: Isn't $R$ the *identity* relation (equality) on $A$? Each element is connected with and only with itself.

Comment: @Berci do u mean to say its not ant-symmetric? If soo could you explain why?

Comment: I meant that $R==$. And that is antisymmetric: $(a=b) \land (b=a)\implies a=b$.

Comment: I mean how would you draw a hasse diagram in which each element is connected with itself?

Comment: @jack : You put your $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ OUTSIDE of $\TeX$.  Standard size and spacing conventions are not followed when you do that.  Look at my recent edit.

Comment: This question seems closely related to [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/353105).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a [partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) $R$, so a [Hasse diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) is possible.  As always, we have an upward edge between two vertices $i$ and $j$, with $i \neq j$, whenever $iRj$ and there is no $k$ such that $iRkRj$.

In this case, as noted in the comments,
\begin{align*}
R &= \{(a,b):a^3=b^3\} \\
  &= \{(a,b):a=b\} \\
  &= \{(a,a):a \in \{-7,\ldots,7\}\}. \\
\end{align*}
So $R$ is the partial order $=$.

So, the edges are between $i,j \in \{-7,\ldots,7\}$, with $i \neq j$, such that $i=j$.  This never happens, so there's no edges.  So here is the Hasse diagram:

[image: Hasse diagram]