# Is this a partially ordered set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

I was wondering if partially ordered sets could have loops in their diagrams. For example isn't the $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and relation $R=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)\}$ a partially ordered set that has a cycle? $R$ is reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitivy fails for your relation $R$.

As for loops on the diagram, that is not possible due to transitivy, that should become apparent from the algorithm to draw diagrams I describe in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353105/discrete-math-hasse-diagrams/353132#353132).

Comment: Oh right because (1,2) and (2,3) is in R but (1,3) is not. Is that why transitivity fails?

Comment: @Celeritas Exactly. It also fails because $(2,3), (3,1)\in  R$, but $(2,1)\not \in R$.

Comment: I don't get the algorithm because 1)what's Euclidian plane 2)I don't know what it means for x to cover y?

Comment: @Celeritas Just think of the euclidean place as $\Bbb R^2$. Intuitively, $x$ covers $y$ if there aren't any elements between $x$ and $y$. For instance [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Hasse_diagram_of_powerset_of_3.svg/300px-Hasse_diagram_of_powerset_of_3.svg.png), $\{x,y\}$ and $\{x,z\}$ both cover $\{x\}$, but $\{x,y,z\}$ and $\{y,z\}$ don't (for different reasons).

Comment: Ok but I don't see how an algorithm for drawing Hasse diagram explains why there can't be any loops in a partially ordered set.

Comment: If there is a loop, it means you're able to go from a vertice to another vertice and back (perhaps going through some more vertices in between), but in a diagram you can only "go up". If you're coming down too you're getting something like $\color{blue}x<y<z<\color{blue}x$.

Comment: Right. I really don't see such a violation x<y<z<x what is wrong with that? Seriously what rule does that violate?

Comment: @Celeritas You get $x<x$ and that can't happen.

Comment: :( why not? Sorry but that's not apparent to me. < isn't the actual less than operator, right, it's the precedes operator?

Comment: @Celeritas In a partial order, $a<b\iff a\leq b \land a\neq b$, replacing $a$ and $b$ with $x$ yields $x<x\iff x\leq x \land \color{red}{x\neq x}$. Is this clear?

Comment: Yes that's clear but are we talking about the less than operator, or something different? My understanding is in the context of partial orders the operator $\prec$ is used which isn't actually the same as <. I think that's what my confusion is.

Comment: @Celeritas $\prec$ is used for covering. Notice the name of the command `\prec`, it comes from *preciding* which is the same as covering. In my comment above $<$ intuitively is 'less than', yes and it is different from $\prec$. What exactly aren't you understanding at the moment?

Comment: You say you can't have $x<x$ and I agree with that but isn't the irrelevant in this conversation since we're actually concerned with $x \prec x$ and I know of no reason why this is an invalid statement.

Comment: @Celeritas The very definition of $\prec$ implies that $a\prec b\implies a<b$.

Comment: What is the definition of $\prec$? My textbook doesn't have it and I can't Google search it because it doesn't have a name.

Comment: @Celeritas It's what denoted [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_relation) as '$<\cdot$', $a\prec b$ means '$b$ covers $a$'.