# Is it possible to do a Hasse Diagram for divisibility on the following set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

{2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 25}

In Hasse Diagrams of divisibility am I allowed to cross edges? If so then I believe I have a solution, if not then here's where my problem lies.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/353132/55235) for an algorithm to draw hasse diagrams for finite posets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a Hasse Diagram. Any finite poset can be made into a Hasse diagram, and your set ordered by divisibility forms a poset. There is also no requirement for Hasse diagrams to be planar, or else the most common examples of posets, such as $B_n$ for $n > 2$ would not be "diagrammable".

Answer (score 2):

Yes -- there's no requirement that a Hasse diagram has to be planar.